# JQuery HTML Unterminated String Literal Error If HTML Contains Spaces

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-ui

This code gets inserted into the page's HTML, by setting it as part of an element's innerHtml. It creates a button-like span that when clicked, opens a JQueryUI window with some constant text and with the text "Thiswindow" below that.

```
string custom_training_html = "Thiswindow"; // Note this line here.
link = "<span class=\"start_course_button\" onclick=";
link += "javascript:$(\"#temp_test_window\").dialog({minWidth:800,minHeight:600});$(\"#temp_test_custom_html\").html('" + custom_training_html + "');>Test JQueryUI";
link += "</span>\n";
```

However, if I change the text "Thiswindow" to "This window", I get:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

It's the presence of a space, anywhere in this HTML, that breaks the code. Other questions on this site say the problem is line breaks in the HTML, but I haven't got any, I think. I'm just building a string containing the `<span>` code, and the only difference between a working version and a non-working version is that one contains a space character. What's wrong?

FYI, the window that gets opened looks like this:

```
<div id="temp_test_window" title="Chaucer's Prologue (The Monk)">
    A monk there was, one made for mastery<br />... [snip]
    <div id="temp_test_custom_html">Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: I've cleaned up the code to put the JS into its own function, but that hasn't solved the problem. In my main .aspx file I have:

```
function GenerateTestTrainingContent(content)
            {
                $('#temp_test_window').dialog({minWidth:800,minHeight:600});
                $('#temp_test_custom_html').html(content);
            }
[and later, outside the <script> tags:]
<div id="temp_test_custom_html">Content Goes Here</div>
```

And in the .aspx.cs file I have this code creating some HTML as "link":

```
link = "<span class='start_course_button' onclick=javascript:GenerateTestTrainingContent('OneWord');>";
link += "Test JQueryUI</span>\n";
```

That works, giving me a link that summons a pop-up JQueryUI window in which the text "OneWord" appears. However, if I change 'OneWord' to 'One Word' in the same code, I get:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
javascript:GenerateTestTrainingContent('One
```

So again, no space = works, any spaces = doesn't work.

Comment: JavaScript does not have such thing as "string" variable definition, you always use keyword "var" for those...

Comment: I should have noted: the code above is C# that creates JS. The string variable is a C# variable.

Comment: The C# error suggests that the string is not terminated properly. But it does not indicate which specific String or portion of the string. I suspect that you're missing a quote wrapper for the content of the `onclick` attribute. I would also suggest moving the JS code to it's own script block to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, I would move the JS to it's own `<script>` block. I would also cleanup the use of `"` versus `'` to make things less confusing.

```
string custom_training_html = "This window"; // Note this line here.
string link = "";
link += "<span class='start_course_button'>Test JQueryUI</span>\r\n";
link += "<script>\r\n";
link += "$('#temp_test_window').dialog({ autoOpen: false, minWidth:800, minHeight:600 });\r\n";
link += "$('#temp_test_custom_html').html('" + custom_training_html + "');\r\n";
link += "$('.start_course_button').click(function(){ $('#temp_test_window').dialog('open'); });\r\n";
link += "</script>\r\n";
```

Comment: Moving the JS to its own block and checking the use of quote marks are good ideas. However, I'm still in a situation where a string with no spaces works, but one with spaces does not. See edited post.

Comment: @Snow That's a really odd one, but I think it's related to C# and not JS. I don't have a ASP.NET test area, so I can't really test that element of the problem. You may want to edit your post, include details about what .NET Framework you're using etc.

Comment: @Snow can you not call the `click` event from the separated JS code? Why are you running it in the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Also have you tried encoding the string? `link = "<span class='start_course_button' onclick=javascript:GenerateTestTrainingContent('One%20Word');>";
link += "Test JQueryUI</span>\n";`